# I have a script running on Firefox slowing computer

Tags: firefox, script

My computer has gotten really slow.  The messages are that there is a script running on firefox.  I don't really know what that means.  I have defragged and used CC(crap cleaner) and Avast virus.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The script could be either a user script (something you loaded to your browser like an add-on), or Javascript running on a web site.  Many websites make heavy use of scripts, and they aren't always well-behaved.

Assuming from the question it's a website script, you can load an add-on like [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) (on the Add-ons tab, search for new extensions and enter the name as the search term).  There are a number of such add-ons; NoScript is one that's very effective.

This will block scripts on websites unless you allow them.  The downside is that many sites won't work unless you allow the scripts (even Super User will give you a message that it will "work better" if you allow scripts).  So especially when you first install it, you'll frequently run into problems with sites that don't work correctly, which require manual intervention to allow scripts to run on the site.  Your choices get stored, so as you deal with your frequent sites, intervention requirements will become less frequent.

NoScript is one that shows you every script that is trying to run on the page, and lets you control each one individually.  So you can allow ones needed by the site but block ones that add advertising or other things you don't want.  Some other add-ons, like [Disable Javascript](https://github.com/dpacassi/disable-javascript), remember your setting for each site, but Javascript is either on or off at the site, and there's usually an icon to toggle it when you encounter a new problem site.

Most people load one of these add-ons to block advertising and speed up browsing.  But it will also solve your hanging script problem by not letting it run in the first place.